# C# Button update(refresh) xml Value

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio, xpath

I'm working on a small weather application in Visual studio and everything is working except for one function.
 I can't get my update-button(btnUpdate_Click) to work. What it should do is refresh or update the temperature values from xml-file (url) in real time !

I've tried reset all label showing the temperature to string.empty then reload(refresh)the value again using the XMLDocument but it did not work :/
need help!

Comment: It would be much easier for you to use binding for such purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I am missing something, but I would try to move the work done in the ThreadPool in a separate method of the class TemperaturePresenter.
I would call this method from the constructor to have the actual behavior, but, now I could call again that method also inside the button click

```
  public TemperaturePresenter()
  {
     _view = new MainView(this);
     serverDoc = new XmlDocument();
     responseDoc = new XmlDocument();
     LoadTemperatures();
  }
  public void LoadTemperatures()
  {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        delegate
        {
            .. a lot of things to check here ...
        }
  }

  ,,,,,


  public void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {            
     _parent.LoadTemperatures();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

serverDoc.Load(

try

serverDoc.LoadXML() method